# Specific regular expression pattern

Tags: c#, regex

Say I have this example string

```
    <td><a href="/one-two-three/menus" title="test"</td>
<td><a href="/one-two-three/menus/13:00 title="test"</td>
<td><a href="/one-two-three/schedule/could be multiple delimiters/14:00 title="test"</td>
```

I want to use regex to get 2 results only when the full string starts with `/one-two-three` and ends with `hh:mm`. Eg I want to get:

```
/one-two-three/menus/13:00
/one-two-three/schedule/could be multiple delimiters/14:00
```

I've tried regex pattern `/one-two-three[\s\S]+?[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]`

but this gives

```
Found 2 matches:
1./one-two-three/menus" title="test"</td>     <td><a href="/one-two-three/menus/13:00
2./one-two-three/schedule/could be multiple delimiters/14:00
```

I can see why I get the results but my question is what pattern can I use to exclude parts without `hh:mm` where there can be any number of delimiters between `/one-two-three` and `hh:mm`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the HTML structure is important to you, [regex is the wrong approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Otherwise (if you can match the string anywhere as long as it's surrounded by `"`), you might want to try this:

```
/one-two-three[^"]+?[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]
```

`[\s\S]` basically mean **any** character. But you only want characters that are not `"`, because this marks the end of the path.

Comment: Thanks for that. HTML is not important in my case although I have seen that link before. Most of the parsers that get suggested (eg HTML agility pack etc) are fine when dealing with a few pages but far too slow when hundreds or thousands of responses are to be processed. :)

Comment: Well yeah, the point of that page is not, that it's "not elegant" to use regex to parse HTML. It's literally impossible, because HTML is not a regular language. It's only possible to solve HTML problems with regex if your problem is very limited in terms of regarding the HTML structure.

Answer (score 0):

try

search
`".*\"/{one-two-three}{.*}{[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]}.*"`

replace with

`\1 = one-two-three`
`\2 = middle parts`
`\3 = hh:mm`

if you replace with `\1\3` it will eliminate middle portion

Hope this helps :)